# How to build this page use HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a question that I don't know how to solve. I tried to use the FullCalendar plugin, but failed.

Bad, the picture is not uploaded!

Comment: Could you post some code of what you've tried?

Comment: Hello, I used the plug-in FullCalendar to achieve, in the HTML file, I set the mintime and maxTime. The final interface effect is on the left shows the specific time, like 6am and 7am. 10pm, but the effect I want is on the left show only three lines, from top to bottom in turn is morning, afternoon and evening. So I don't know what to do.

Comment: Are you including all the required files? You need the `fullcalendar.css`, `jquery.min.js`, `moment.min.js`, `fullcalendar.js`. Best if loaded in that order according to the [docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've used in the past when utilizing the jQuery full calendar plugin:

You need to include both the `CSS` and `JS` files for it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fullcalendar-2.2.6.min.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fullcalendar-2.2.6.min.js"></script>
```

#### Then the jQuery:

```
$(function() {  
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        defaultDate: '', // can be dynamically set to highlight current day
        eventLimit: true, // allows "more" link when too many events in a day
        events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2015-07-01'
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: '2015-07-08',
                end: '2015-07-09'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2015-07-09T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2015-07-16T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Conference',
                start: '2015-07-12',
                end: '2015-07-13'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2015-07-12T10:30:00',
                end: '2015-07-12T12:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Lunch',
                start: '2015-07-12T12:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2015-07-12T14:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Happy Hour',
                start: '2015-07-12T17:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Dinner',
                start: '2015-07-12T20:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Birthday Party',
                start: '2015-07-13T07:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Click for Google',
                url: 'http://google.com/',
                start: '2015-07-28'
            }
        ]
    }); // end of calendar constructor
}); // end of document.ready function
```

#### Then just one HTML element needed for the calendar:

`<div id="calendar"></div>`

Comment: Well, I know what you mean. May be I do not know, the key is not to upload pictures to let you see the effect...

Comment: I don't quite understand, but if you're legitimately looking for help on here you are making it difficult for users to provide you with an acceptable answer.

Comment: I posted a comment for you to provide us with what you have tried or at least some more details, but you did not. I even posted an answer despite your vague question and comments and you are still not providing the details needed to give you an acceptable answer. Please read the [SO documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question then try updating your post.

Comment: The result is:<br />

|         | Sunday           | Monday  |...|
| ------------- |:-------------:| :-----:|----:|
| 6:00am      | | |...|
| 7:00am      |  ...    |   |...|
| 8:00am |      |    |...|
| ... |    ...  | ...   |...|

<br />
But I want is like this:<br />

|         | Sunday           | Monday  |...|
| ------------- |:-------------:| :-----:|----:|
| Morning     | | |...|
| Afternoon      |  ...    |   |...|
| evening |      |    |...|